# Firestore access rules - only read documents with specific uid

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm a little bit lost playing with Firestore rules and my Flutter app. I have a collection "posts" ( [Screenshot of Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3gU.jpg) ). There I would like to allow every authenticated user to create new documents. But only the one who created it should be able to read, update and delete the document. I have following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I access my screen with StreamBuilder that calls Firestore I get "The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation" although the uid in app is the same as in the documents uid entry. My StreamBuilder streamlooks like this:

```
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('created', descending: _showLatest)
            .snapshots(),
```

Access rules seem to work, whenever I change back to the original "allow all" rules I can read and write all posts. Would this rule match if I want a list of all documents the user created? Or does it only match on a single document?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore [security rules do not filter the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) on their own. Instead they merely inspect the query to ensure it only requests data that is is permitted to.

So since your rules enforce that the user can only read data they own, the query has to also request only that data. If it requests more data (as yours does), it'll get rejeced).

The solution is to add a condition to your query that matches the check in your rules:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy('created', descending: _showLatest)
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid) // 
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! Had to add an index after that too but Firebase already suggested the right one via http link.